# Create index list for np.split from the list that already has number for each section

Tags: python, numpy

I have two lists of numbers

```
list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
number = [3,2,1,3]
```

I want to create index for np.split from `number`

```
index = [3,5,6,9]
```

for

```
np.split(list, index)
```

Expected outcome

```
[[1,2,3],[4,5],[6],[7,8,9]]
```

I tried something like `newlist = [x+number[0:index(x)] for x in list]` but it still does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Approach #1**

If we want to use [`np.split`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.split.html) resulting in a list of arrays, we need to use `np.cumsum` on those *indexes* to give us indices where we need to split the input list -

```
np.split(list1, np.cumsum(number)[:-1])
```

Sample run -

```
In [36]: list1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
    ...: number = [3,2,1,3]
    ...: 

In [37]: np.split(list1, np.cumsum(number)[:-1])
Out[37]: [array([1, 2, 3]), array([4, 5]), array([6]), array([7, 8, 9])]
```

---

**Approach #2**

To have a list of lists, another approach with a loop comprehension again using `cumsum` -

```
idx = np.r_[0,np.cumsum(number)]
out = [list1[idx[i]:idx[i+1]] for i in range(len(idx)-1)]
```

Sample run -

```
In [45]: idx = np.r_[0,np.cumsum(number)]

In [46]: [list1[idx[i]:idx[i+1]] for i in range(len(idx)-1)]
Out[46]: [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6], [7, 8, 9]]
```